# Add text to beginning of first line and different text to beginning of all subsequent lines in file

Tags: csv, batch-file

source file contents (csv):

```
430,081216,081216,131231231231,,'',8686866,'Shamrock',,
1, ,5,,'',, ,01234567,32.50,
2,-,3,,'',, ,382847,25.92,
3, ,5,,'',, ,98765430,32.89,
```

target file needs to be (csv):

```
H,430,081216,081216,131231231231,,'',8686866,'Shamrock',,
D,1, ,5,,'',, ,01234567,32.50,
D,2,-,3,,'',, ,382847,25.92,
D,3, ,5,,'',, ,98765430,32.89,
```

I need to add an "H," to the beginning of the first line in the file, and a "D," to the beginning of all subsequent lines in the file, and save off as another file name.  I don't know the best way to do this.  I'm a newbie at this and would appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Is it seriously DOS? Like the OS from the 80s? Or is it just the regular command prompt in Windows? (There actually is a difference.)

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: [DOS and Windows cmd are different things](http://superuser.com/q/451432/241386)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this simpler method could be easier to understand...

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "letter=H"
(for /F "delims=" %%a in (source.csv) do (
   echo !letter!,%%a
   set "letter=D"
)) > target.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q39652124.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"
SET "hord="
(
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 IF DEFINED hord (ECHO D%%a) ELSE (SET "hord=D"&ECHO H%%a)

)
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir`, `filename1`, `outfile` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q39652124.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Produces the file defined as %outfile%

Read each line of the file, assigning the line-content to `%%a`. Since `hord` is set to *nothing* at the start, it is not defined, so set `hord` to something and the line prefixed by `H` is `echo`ed. Now `hord` is defined, so output each further line prefixed by `D`.

Comment: Thanks, Magoo!
This works, with a few changes for my data,  but the basic code/logic works perfect.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Although you did not show any own efforts, I decided to provide a quick answer. Please learn and do some work on your own next time before asking a question!

So here is a script that modifies all the files provided by command line:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

for %%F in (%*) do (
    set "FLAG=#"
    for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ('
        type "%%~F" ^& ^
        REM ^> "%%~F" break
    ') do (
        REM >> "%%~F" (
            if defined FLAG (
                echo H,%%L
                set "FLAG="
            ) else (
                echo D,%%L
            )
        REM )
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

**After having tested, remove the three upper-case `REM` commands from the script!**

Note that it *modifies the given files without prompting* and *without checking* whether or not the first column alread contains `H` and `D`!